# specify multiple filenames in one line. bash

Tags: bash, logrotate

guys. im trying to add to logrotate files from a some directory. it should be either *.txt files or *_log files. wtat's the right syntax for this:

```
/var/www/html/groupware/horde_logs/[*.txt|*_log]{
missingok
notifempty
sharedscripts
size=5129k
delaycompress
postrotate
endscript
}
```

~

or it should be:

```
..{*.txt|*_log} or ..(*.txt|*_log)?
```

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be `*{.txt,_log}` (note the comma, not the pipe). However, after a quick look at the source to logrotate (Ubuntu Saucy) I see the flag `GLOB_BRACE` to enable this GNU extension isn't present. Thus, you have to do something like

```
/var/www/html/groupware/horde_logs/*.txt /var/www/html/groupware/horde_logs/*_log {
  ...
}
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take note of this. i was thinking to use [^.#]* but figured out, that it will rotate over all files. so i'd rather use `/var/www/html/groupware/horde_logs/*.txt /var/www/html/groupware/horde_logs/*_log`